# Finding file location of snippets

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a bunch of snippets installed. Some of them are intrusive and I would like to change their tab insertion code. Is there any way to quickly open the edit file of a snippet that I find from the Control+Shift+P directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sublime Text 2, in a word, no. The Command Palette does not have that functionality built-in. However, if you select `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` your OS will open up an Explorer/Finder/Nautilus/whatever window of the `Packages` directory. All packages/plugins are in (hopefully clearly-named) subdirectories, so if you don't like some Rails snippets, for example, look in the `Rails` directory for a likely file with a `.sublime-snippet` extension. These files are XML-based, and can be opened right in Sublime for editing.

Please note that this method only works in this straightforward manner with Sublime Text 2. In ST3, unless otherwise specified by the package author, all packages are in `.sublime-package` zipfiles, and are stored in a few different locations. To ease things, my good friend [@skuroda](https://github.com/skuroda) wrote the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin, which allows the user to navigate through ST3 packages, view/edit files contained therein, and expand whole packages to the aforementioned `Packages` directory for editing of any file.